# Triangles whose two vertices are two consecutive vertices of a regular polygon and other one is the center of the polygon are congruent.

Tags: geometry, polygons

Can anyone please help me to understand why the triangles in the following Regular Polygon are congruent?
 I supposed the **definition of a regular polygon** is -----In Euclidean geometry, a regular polygon is a polygon that is equiangular (all angles are equal in measure) and equilateral (all sides have the same length).

Perhaps it is too trivial to be on this site. But I am really having hard time to see it.[image]

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. The two triangles are congruent on the SSS test or the SAS test. Or just note that you can rotate one into the other by a rotation about the centre.

Comment: How SSS? Can you please elaborate?@almagest

Comment: Please keep the definition of the regular Polygon in mind. I am not allowed to use more than that.@almagest

Comment: @sari. If you accept that the vertices lie on a circle, then the problem is trivial. So you are really asking how you prove that the vertices of a regular polygon lie on a circle.[oh, SSS means side, side, side, and SAS means two sides and included angle - two sufficient conditions for triangles to be congruent.]

Comment: Absolutely right.. If I can prove that the vertices lie on a circle, I will be done.  @almagest

Comment: Can you give any hint to prove that?@almagest

Comment: Let $A,C$ be the two vertices adjacent to vertex $B$. Let the bisectors of $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ meet at $O$ and the bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ meet at $O'$. Then  triangles $AOB,BO'C$ are congruent. So $O,O'$ must coincide. Continuing round the circle, we find that all the vertices are equidistant from $O$.

Comment: How AOB and BO'C are congruent?@almagest

Comment: The ASA test: $AB=BC$ and $\angle OAB=\angle O'BC$ and $\angle OBA=\angle O'CB$.